# Parsing json returns only one object in django jquery

Tags: jquery, json, django

Friends, i'm trying to get ajax json response in django.

While the console log shows every json object, the same is not true while parsing the json and adding a field to a division in html. Only one object's field shows up.

my javascript is as follows

```
$("#all_questions").on("click",
    function(event){
        all_questions();
    }
);

function all_questions()
{
    console.log("all_questions() working..");


    $.ajax({
       url : "/questions", 
       type : "GET", // http method
       data : { },

       success : function(json) {
       console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
       $("#content").empty();
       data = JSON.parse(json);
       $.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
            $('#content').html(obj.fields.title);
        });
    }
    ,


   error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {

       console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); 
   }
  });
}
```

I can't figure out where i'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

`$('#content').html(obj.fields.title);`

Every time you refresh html, you only pass one value to it. Try appending the content in an html file, or creating multiple instances (as a list ro something)